# Java/scala BigDecimal parsing 128 bit hex value

Tags: scala, hex, bigdecimal, number-formatting, 128-bit

I have a number, in this case it is 61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada.

I would like to work with it's numeric representation.

In python I would do:

```
 number = 61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada
```

But I am using Scala, not python.

I have tried:

```
scala> val bd = BigDecimal("61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada")
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

And:

```
scala> val bd = BigDecimal("0x61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada")
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

If the number were smaller, I could just do:

```
scala> val bd = 0x61d54e
bd: Int = 6411598
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scala> BigInt("61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada",16)
res0: scala.math.BigInt = 130042665859304569025379016689359780570
```

Comment: Or:
scala> new java.math.BigInteger("61d54e71b6c8409f9586ffd4cf9ffada", 16)
res16: java.math.BigInteger = 130042665859304569025379016689359780570